# Refresh parent page after closing modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, modal-dialog

When a user opens this modal, they can see their shopping cart information and delete items(other jquery) on the modal.

But how could I refresh the parent page after a user closes up the modal?

I read several posts but did not find any useful information for my situation.  I know I need to use something like `window.location.reload(true);`  Where should I put that in the code?

```
$(function(){

    $('#main').off('click.login').on('click.login',function(){

        $('body').loadmodal({

            id:'cart',
            title:'Shopping Cart',
            url:'/cartDisplay/',
            width: '550px',
        }); 


    });
});
```

**Update**

```
    $(function(){
    $('#main').off('click.login').on('click.login',function(){

        $('body').loadmodal({

            id:'cart',
            title:'Shopping Cart',
            url:'/polls/cartDisplay/',
            width: '550px',

        }); 


    });

    $('#cart').on('hidden', function () {
        window.location.reload(true);
    })

});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this.

```
  $("#cart").on('hide', function () {
        window.location.reload();
    });
```

Answer (score 14):

I assume that you are using Twitter Bootstrap

Bootstrap 3

```
$('#cart').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    window.location.reload(true);
})
```

Bootstrap 2.3.2

```
$('#cart').on('hidden', function () {
   window.location.reload(true);
})
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using bootstrape.  I put you codes inside my current jquery. When I close the modal, the parent page still does not refresh.

Comment: Also would like to request you to see console can u see any error.

Comment: I am using BS 2.3.2 I can not see any error. It simply closed up the modal and nothing happened to the parent page

Comment: Also I changed from"hidden.bs.modal' to"hidden" it still does not work.

Comment: After I changed #cart to document it seems it can refresh the parent page now

Comment: Thats great you fixed it

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell, [`jquery.loadmodal.js`](https://github.com/doconix/jquery.loadmodal.js/tree/master) has `bootstrap.js` as a dependency, so its modals are still subject to bootstrap's methods.

In that case, you can simply bind to `hidden.bs.modal`

```
...
$('#yourModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    location.reload();
});
...
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean I need to write a new jquery? Or Put those codes inside my current Jquery

Comment: No, just replaced `#yourModal` in my code with the ID of the modal in your code. Looks like you're calling it `#cart`, so `$('#cart').on...`

Comment: Thank you. I made changes. but I seems it still does not work. I updated my post. may you look at it?

Comment: Thank you it works now. I changed #cart to document.

Answer (score 0):

Where you open the nyroModal window, just add this callback function:

```
 callbacks: {
       afterClose: function() {
              window.location.reload();
            }
        }
```