# Refreshing the page while closing the modal popup using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**My Problem :**

I have a modal form which pops up when I click on a submit button . The modal form allows the user to fill in a set of fields and request for a demo from an organization . The form data is then inserted into a mysql database using codeigniter . When the user submits the validated form , the modal popup simply displays a success message and a dynamically generated button (replacing the previous form ), which allows the user to close the modal form .

When I click on the dynamically generated **close** button , the modal form closes and refreshes the page .

**However , I am unable to do the same (refresh the page) when I click on the close icon on the top right corner on the modal form .**

I have tried using the following code , but I am not able to refresh the page on the close event of the modal popup.

```
$('#mymodal').on("hidden", function() {
          location.reload();;
         });
```

I have also tried using the following code :

```
$('#mymodal').on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
              location.reload();;
             });
```

I have used **jquery.mask.js** and **jquery.validate.min.js** for form validation for the modal form.

**My research :**

I have gone through the following questions on Stack Overflow :

- [Refresh parent page after closing modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952713/refresh-parent-page-after-closing-modal)
- [How to reload page on closing a Bootstrap 3 modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578315/how-to-reload-page-on-closing-a-bootstrap-3-modal)
- [Refresh parent page when jQuery UI Dialog is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826173/refresh-parent-page-when-jquery-ui-dialog-is-closed)
- [Hook into dialog close event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171928/hook-into-dialog-close-event)

**My modal form :**

```
<div class="container">
<!-- <form name="" id="" action="" method="get"> -->
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="margin:0 auto;">Request a Demo</button>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">  
    <div class="modal-dialog" id="idmodaldialog">    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <form name="frmdemo" id="idfrmdemo" method="post">
      <div class="modal-content">        
         <div class="modal-header" align="center">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"><strong>Request a Demo</strong></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="idmodalcontent">                         
             <div class="row">
             <div class="form-group col-md-6">
             <label for="txtfirstname">FIRST NAME</label>
             <input name="txtfirstname" type="text" class="form-control required" placeholder="Please enter your first name" id="idfirstname" >
             </div>
             <div class="form-group col-md-6">
             <label for="txtlastname">LAST NAME</label>
             <input name="txtlastname" type="text" class="form-control required" placeholder="Please enter your last name" id="idlastname">            
             </div>           
             </div>             
             <div class="form-group">
             <label for="Email">EMAIL</label>
             <input type="email" name="txtemail" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email id" id="idemail">
             <div class="divstyle">(Please enter your email id in block letters)</div>
             </div>             
             <div class="form-group">
             <label for="idcompany">COMPANY</label>
             <input type="text" name="txtcompany" placeholder="Please enter the name of your company" class="form-control" id="idcompany" >
             </div>             
             <div class="form-group">
             <label for="Phone">PHONE</label>
             <input type="tel" name="txtphone" placeholder="Please enter your phone number" class="form-control" id="idphone">             
             </div>
            <div class="form-group">
             <label for="">MODE OF CONTACT</label>
             <select name="selmode" id="idmode" class="form-control">
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <option value="email">Email</option>
            <option value="phone">Phone</option>  
            </select>
             </div>         
         </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <input type="submit" id="idsubmit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-warning" />
        </div>
      </div>
      </form> 
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

**My Jquery Form validation Code :**

```
// Wait for the DOM to be ready
$(function() {  

    $('#mymodal').on("hidden", function() {
          location.reload();;
         });    

    $('#idphone').mask('(000) 000-0000');

    // Initialize form validation on the registration form.
  // It has the name attribute "frmdemo"
  $("form[name='frmdemo']").validate({
    // Specify validation rules 
      rules: {
      // The key name on the left side is the name attribute
      // of an input field. Validation rules are defined
      // on the right side
      "txtfirstname": {required:true,firstnameval:true},
      "txtlastname": {required:true,lastnameval:true},
      "txtemail": {
        required: true,        
        // Specify that email should be validated
        // by the built-in "email" rule
        email: true,
        emailval:true 
      },
      "txtcompany": {
          required: true,
          companyval:false    
      },

      "txtphone" : {
         required : true,
         usphoneval:true 
      },   

      "selmode" :{
         required : true 
      } 
    },
    // Specify validation error messages
    messages: {
      txtfirstname: {
          required:"Please enter your first name" ,
          firstnameval:"Enter proper first name"
          //firstnameval:"Enter only alphabets ",         
            },
     txtlastname: {
                  required:"Please enter your last name " ,
                  lastnameval:"Enter proper last name"
                  //firstnameval:"Enter only alphabets ",         
                    },    
      txtemail: {
                  required : "Please enter a valid email address",     
                  emailval : "Please enter your corporate email id"       
      },     
      txtcompany: {
          required :"Please enter the name of your company",
          companyval:"Enter a proper company name"
      },         
      txtphone: {
          required :"Please enter your phone number",
          usphoneval :"Please enter a valid phone number"  
      },
         selmode:"Please select the mode in which we should contact you"
    },

    // Make sure the form is submitted to the destination defined
    // in the "action" attribute of the form when valid  

    submitHandler: function(form) {
       // form.submit();
      $('#idmodalcontent').html('Form submitted successfully');

      var input = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'button', name:'btnsubmit', value:'Close', id:'idclose',"class":"btn btn-warning"});    

      //"data-dismiss":'modal',

      $(".modal-footer").html(input);

      $("#idclose").on("click",function(){
         location.reload();
        });              

      /*$('#idmodalcontent').modal({
              onClose: function(dialog){
                location.reload(true);
            }
        }); 
      */
      return false;        
    }        
  });


//add your own custom validation rule

  //US phone format
    $.validator.addMethod("usphoneval", function(value,element)
    {       
        //^\(?([d]{3})\)?[. ]?([d]{3})[. ]?([d]{4})$

        if (/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[ ]?([0-9]{3})[-]?([0-9]{4})$/.test(value)) 
        {
            return true;

        } else {

            return false;           
        }       

    },function() 
    { 
    });


    //first name : only alphabets
    $.validator.addMethod("firstnameval", function(value,element)
            {       
                //^\(?([d]{3})\)?[. ]?([d]{3})[. ]?([d]{4})$

                if (/^[a-zA-Z]{1,256}$/.test(value)) 
                {
                    return true;

                } else {

                    return false;           
                }       

            },function() 
            { 
            });

    $.validator.addMethod("lastnameval", function(value,element)
            {       

                //first character alphabet - rest alphanumeric
                if (/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{0,256}$/.test(value)) 
                {

                    return true;


                } else {

                    return false;
                }       

            },function() 
            {           
            });

    //validate company - first character alphabet,rest only alphabet,dot,spaces
    $.validator.addMethod("companyval", function(value,element)
            {       
                if (/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z. ]{1,256}$/.test(value)) 
                {
                    return true;                    

                } else {

                    return false;
                }       

            },function() 
            { 
            });     

    $.validator.addMethod("emailval", function(value,element)
            {       

            var n = value.lastIndexOf('@');
            var extension = value.substring(n+1).toLowerCase();
            if (extension == "gmail.com" || extension=="aol.com"|| extension=="facebook.com"|| extension=="googlemail.com"                  
            || extension=="hotmail.com" || extension=="hotmail.co.uk" || extension=="yahoo.com" || extension=="yahoo.co.uk"
            || extension=="live.com"    || extension=="att.net" || extension=="comcast.net" || extension=="gmx.com"     
            || extension=="mac.com" || extension=="me.com" || extension=="sbcglobal.net" || extension=="verizon.net"                
            || extension=="msn.com" || extension=="mail.com"|| extension=="email.com" || extension=="games.com"
            || extension=="gmx.net" || extension=="hush.com" ) {

                return false ;

            } else {

                return true;

            }

            },function() 
            { 
            }); 
});
```

Comment: You have an id on your close button so why not use `$('#idclose').on('click',function() {});`

Comment: @A.OzanEkici it's better to use modal's onclose events as it would trigger in other cases as well e.g. if user closes the modal using escape key. Depends on use case ultimately.

Comment: Yep @MohitBhardwaj you are right. But that was just an another way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plz try this code:
you have just wrong #mymodel id name in your code.

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
 location.reload();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , Hope it helps!

```
$(".close").click(function(){
    bootbox.hideAll();
    location.reload();
});
```